# What's the best way to create folder structures based on conventions in C#

Tags: c#

My C# Application handles multiple user projects. The projects are application specific (I'm not talking about dev projects). The projects files are stored in a particular folder structure. Such a structure could be:

- ProjectA

  - Import
  - Export

    - Products
    - Documentation
  - Customerinfo
  - ProjectDescription.xml

While adding a new project I need to automatically create a default folder structure (directories and files) based on a certain convention / schema.

What's the best way to:

1. define such a convention / schema
2. create the structure

in C#? Are there any frameworks? Do I need to build it manually using Factory methods?

Comment: I doubt it's possible to suggest a "best way" for defining a convention for a project you didn't describe. Creating a structure, if it's really complex, might be done with a simple batch file. Or, are you talking about generally defining a schema for specifying the folder hierarchy, and then building the tree out of it?

Comment: Just set up a project template...

Comment: @Groo Yes, I want to define a schema (convention) and build the structure out of it. I updated the title.

Answer (score 4):

General suggestions about structuring .NET projects:

- [How to setup a .NET Development Tree](http://mikebroberts.files.wordpress.com/2007/01/howtosetupadotnetdevelopmenttree.pdf) by Mike Roberts
- [How do you organize your code?](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/howdoyouorganizeyourcode.aspx) by Scott Hanselman

Once you have a well-structured project template, then you can make copies of it, and use these copies to start user projects.

A better approach would be to put the template project under version control, and check it out on developer machines. Use a [DVCS](http://www.ericsink.com/vcbe/): developers could clone the template project to start user projects, and template modifications could be distributed by pulling changes from the template project repo to the user project repos.

A .NET development tree generator: [Tree Surgeon](http://treesurgeon.codeplex.com/)

Comment: I'm talking about a custom user project. The schema for the structure is application specific. I will update my question to avoid misunderstandings.

Comment: The resources pointed to in this answer are 14 years old as of today

Answer (score 1):

I would also suggest to read the "Class library design" links in Microsoft's [.NET Framework Guidelines and Best Practices](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184412.aspx). The Folder structure is not the only thing to set in your Project Template. You can customize the AssemblyInfo.cs file, enable/set CodeAnalysis, add CodeAnalysis custom dictionaries, enable/set CodeContracts, add references to common assemblies etc.

After you decide the main structure of your projects, you will have to create a VS Project Template for your team to use.

Have a look at ["Resources about Visual Studio .NET extensibility"](http://www.mztools.com/resources_vsnet_addins.aspx) in the MZ-Tools site. There you will find links to download sections of VS SDK, documentation and articles.

Note also that VS SDK allows you to add custom wizards to be used by your templates. This is a very powerful feature and can help you create rich Project/Item templates.

Comment: Again, it's not about a dev project. It's a custom application specific folder structure, that's contains project specific files and folders.